# GatsbyJS & Wordpress REST API 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, rest, gatsby

I just tried out Wordpress' REST API with GatsbyJS, but I am getting the following errors:

```
success onPreBootstrap — 0.005 s
⠠ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__POST fetched : 6
⠐ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__PAGE fetched : 2
⠈ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_media fetched : 15
⠠ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_types fetched : 1
⡀ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_statuses fetched : 1
⠁ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_taxonomies fetched : 1
⠠ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__CATEGORY fetched : 8
⢀ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__TAG fetched : 5
⠂ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_users fetched : 2
⠐ source and transform nodesThe server response was "401 Unauthorized"
Inner exception message : "You are not currently logged in."
⢀ source and transform nodes -> wordpress__wp_comments fetched : 0
⡀ source and transform nodesThe server response was "401 Unauthorized"
Inner exception message : "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that."
success source and transform nodes — 16.447 s
success building schema — 0.339 s
success createLayouts — 0.015 s
success createPages — 0.004 s
success createPagesStatefully — 0.010 s
success onPreExtractQueries — 0.001 s
success update schema — 0.160 s
success extract queries from components — 0.088 s
success run graphql queries — 0.030 s
success write out page data — 0.003 s
success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
success onPostBootstrap — 0.001 s
```

So far I've only installed `gatsby-source-wordpress` via npm and changed my `gatsby-config` to:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby Default Starter',
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-react-helmet',
    /*
     * Gatsby's data processing layer begins with “source”
     * plugins. Here the site sources its data from Wordpress.
     */
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        /*
        * The base URL of the Wordpress site without the trailingslash and the protocol. This is required.
        * Example : 'gatsbyjswpexample.wordpress.com' or 'www.example-site.com'
        */
        baseUrl: `myurl.com`,
        // The protocol. This can be http or https.
        protocol: `http`,
        // Indicates whether the site is hosted on wordpress.com.
        // If false, then the asumption is made that the site is self hosted.
        // If true, then the plugin will source its content on wordpress.com using the JSON REST API V2.
        // If your site is hosted on wordpress.org, then set this to false.
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        // If useACF is true, then the source plugin will try to import the Wordpress ACF Plugin contents.
        // This feature is untested for sites hosted on Wordpress.com
        useACF: false,
      },
    },
  ],


};
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading gatsby like `npm install --save gatsby@latest`? I've seen some other people report that the WordPress source only works with the latest version, not sure if it's true in your case or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got rid of the `401 Unauthorized` warnings in `gatsby-source-wordpress` plugin ([click here for documentation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-wordpress#how-to-use)).

The warning:

```
Path: /wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?per_page=100&page=1
The server response was "401 Unauthorized"
Inner exception message: "You are not currently logged in."
```

Only include the routes you need using `includedRoutes` setting in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
includedRoutes: [
    "**/posts",
    "**/pages",
    "**/media",
    "**/categories",
    "**/tags",
    "**/taxonomies",
    // "**/users", // uncomment this and watch the warning above reappear!
    "**/menus",
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth a try is to try disabling all your WordPress plugins and see if it works. If so, try re-enabling them one at a time and see which one *could* be causing issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it should basically just work the way I implemented it? I don't have any plugins installed or enabled thus far.

Comment: yea it *should*... have you also tried adding the verbose option to see any errors? `verboseOutput: true` but from what I'm seeing you should at least be seeing your posts and pages

Answer (score 0):

Have been getting th same error. And running `verboseOutput: true` gives the information that it can't access these endpoints:

http://your-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me
http://your-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/settings

Which I guess is normal, because you would have to be logged in to access those pages.

If everything elese works for you, then I think you can ignore it.